# Preserve full surname, get initials of first name (and middle name if some) in pandas column

Tags: python, string, pandas

I have a pandas Dataframe with a column expressing the surname and name of several tennis players like the following one:

```
   | Player              | 
   |---------------------|
0  | 'Roddick Andy'      |
1  | 'Federer Roger'     |
2  | 'Tsonga Jo Wilfred  |
```

I want to keep the full surname and get the initial of the name and middle name if there is. So the pandas column should look like the following one:

```
   | Player            | 
   |-------------------|
0  | 'Roddick A.'      |
1  | 'Federer R.'      |
2  | 'Tsonga J.W.'     | N.B. J.W. with no space
```

Does anyone have suggestions? Thank!

Comment: Without a meaningful way to distinguish between surnames and given names, you may be screwed.

Comment: It'll be difficult to determine whether the surname is the first word or the last...

Comment: @QuangHoang the surname is always the first item in the string

Comment: That's not the case with `Tsonga` :-)

Comment: @QuangHoang Sorry, it was my mistake! I just edited the code! Even for Tsonga, the surname is the first item of the string

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's an approach with `str.extractall` and `groupby`:

```
(df.Player
  .str.extractall('(?P<Surname>\w*)\s(?P<Name>\w*)')
  .groupby(level=0)
  .agg({'Surname':'first',
        'Name': lambda x: x.str[0].add('.').sum()
        })
  .agg(' '.join, axis=1)
)
```

Output:

```
0     Roddick A.
1     Federer R.
2    Tsonga J.W.
dtype: object
```

Comment: Nice approach for sure =)

Comment: It works perfectly! But may I ask you some questions?

Comment: Sure, that was one :-)

Comment: 1. I've never used 'str.extractall('(?P<Surname>\w*)\s(?P<Name>\w*)')' so why do I have to put ?P and \w* before and after the surname and name groups?

2. What does the egg function does in this case?

I'm sorry for the complexity of such questions but you may be very helpful!
Thank you in advance @QuangHoang

Comment: ?P<name> is refer option for named group. That is helpful for the agg later. And the first agg chooses the first surname in the group, first letter for the other name. The second agg just concatenates surname and the abbreviations.

Comment: Great! I understood everything so thank you! But I have found an error which I hope you could help me to solve. When getting the player name which has also a middle name as in the case of Tsonga, rather than getting Tsonga J.W. , I get Tsonga W.J. 
Is it possible to solve this problem? Thank you in advance! @QuangHoang

Answer (score 3):

You could make use of `df.replace` as follows:

```
import pandas as pd 
df = pd.DataFrame({'Player':['Roddick Andy', 'Federer Roger', 'Tsonga Jo Wilfred']})
df = df.replace(r'(?<=\s\w)\w+\s?', value = '.', regex = True)
print(df)
```

---

***Regular Expression:*** `(?<=\s\w)\w+\s?`

- `\w+` - Match any word character at least ones
- `(?<=\s\w)` - Positive lookbehind (step one must be preceded by a single whitespace and any single wordcharacter
- `\s?` - Step one is followed by an optional whitespace.

---

***Results:***

```
        Player
0   Roddick A.
1   Federer R.
2  Tsonga J.W.
```

---

***EDIT:***

***Option 1:***

To swap around the two initials, we could (to maintain the idea of using regular expressions) add another `df.replace`, with a second regular expression.

```
import pandas as pd 
df = pd.DataFrame({'Player':['Roddick Andy', 'Federer Roger', 'Tsonga Jo Wilfred']})
df = df.replace(r'(?<=\s\w)\w+\s?', value = '.', regex = True)
df = df.replace(r'(.(?=\.)\.)(.(?=\.)\.)?', value = r'\2\1', regex = True)
print(df)
```

---

***Regular Expression:*** `(.(?=\.)\.)(.(?=\.)\.)?`

- `(.(?=\.)\.)` - Capture group 1: Match any characer (`.`) that is followed by (positive lookahead) a literal dot, including matching a dot.
- `(.(?=\.)\.)?` - Capture group 2: Optional (`?`) capturing group matching the exact same pattern as capture group 1.

The above isn't very dynamic. But it will work fine when there are a max of two initials. It's also possible to append on it rather easily, however the below option would be more dynamic.

***Option 2:***

Before you continue, may I mention I'm rather new to `Python` so I'm sure that what I done here can be shortened/done much simpler.

The idea here is to `split` and apend the dataframe, then reverse all but the first column to then `join` them back together into a single column in the dataframe, where we then can apply the `df.replace` again.

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'Player':['Roddick Andy', 'Federer Roger', 'Tsonga Jo Wilfred']})
df = df.Player.str.split(None, expand=True).iloc[:, ::-1]
df = df[[list(df.columns)[-1]] + list(df.columns)[:-1]]
df = df[df.columns[0:]].apply(lambda x: ' '.join(x.dropna().astype(str)), axis=1)
df = df.replace(r'(?<=\s\w)\w+\s?', value = '.', regex = True)
print(df)
```

---

***Results:***

```
        Player
0   Roddick A.
1   Federer R.
2  Tsonga W.J.
```

Comment: Nice.... I wish I could wrap my head around "positive look behind" in regex. +1

Comment: Thank @JvdV for your help! Even using this code I have that rather than having  Tsonga J.W. I have Tsonga W.J. so W and J are swopped. How can I solve this problem? Thank you in advance!

Comment: @stud_eco. Any luck?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming every lastname is one word last name:

```
def shorten_name(name):
    name_as_list = name.split(" ")
    last_name = name_as_list[-1]
    first_names = ".".join([w[0] for w in name_as_list[:-1]]) + "."
    return (last_name, first_names)
```

using like this:

```
last_name, first_names_shortened = shorten_name("Jo Wilfried Tsonga")
```